# Laravel Livewire - Get all checkbox value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I've want to add filters on my table. My filters are the level of security of an account.
There is my HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="O" wire:model="level" id="O">
<label for="O">O</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="a" wire:model="level" id="a">
<label for="a">A</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="b" wire:model="level" id="b">
<label for="b">B</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="c" wire:model="level" id="c">
<label for="c">C</label>
```

And there is my Livewire component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class Compliance extends Component
{

    public $level = [];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.compliance', [
            'customers' => $this->row
        ]);
    }

    public function getRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        $query = User::query()
            ->when($this->level, fn($query, $levels) => $query->level($levels));

        return $query;
    }

    public function getRowsProperty()
    {
        return $this->rowsQuery->paginate(20);
    }
}
```

My problem is:
$this->level is always only one value, not an array of value like

```
[
     0 => 'O',
     1 => 'a'
]
```

I would like to have all the checked checkbox everytime i check or uncheck a checkbox.
Thanks for reading

Comment: In livewire you can do dot notation? so wouldn't doing level.0, level.1 ... suffice?

Comment: In HTML? I've tried with level.a level.b in wire:model, but always same problem, in render i've got an array with 0 => 'a' or 0 => 'b' but never the 2 value in the same array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add wire:click. For example, change your input fields like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" wire:click="levelClicked" value="a" wire:model="level" id="a">
```

And in the Compliance component, add a new method:

```
public function levelClicked()
{
    // now the property $this->level will contain all the selected values
}
```

Comment: Just a comment for noobs like me: level var must be declared as
    public $level = [];
in the component, otherwise all of the checkboxes will check at once.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, one can do a click and append to the array, or from the blade do something like this.

```
<form>
  @foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox)
         <div class="mt-1">
              <label class="inline-flex items-center">
              <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $checkbox->id }}" wire:model="level.{{ $checkbox->id }}" class="form-checkbox h-6 w-6">
                   <span class="ml-3 text-sm">{{ $checkbox->name }}</span>
               </label>
          </div>
  @endforeach
</form>
```

This way when you submit the form, all values will be inside the `$level` array.